# Hive query on spark engine going in an infinite loop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, cloudera

I have installed CDH5.6 with Spark on my VM.
In Hive when I am submitting any query with `mr` engine it runs all good, but when I am changing it to `spark`, logs show that it is submitting the job and going in an infinite loop like this:

```
hive> set hive.execution.engine=spark;
hive> create table landing.tmp as select * from landing.employee;
Query ID = root_20171203165454_64ca3a41-25af-4cd5-a2c1-9b7c9e8f49cd
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Spark Job = cf7a1eff-7ba6-48f5-90dd-f5de3794c36e

Query Hive on Spark job[0] stages:
0

Status: Running (Hive on Spark job[0])
Job Progress Format
CurrentTime StageId_StageAttemptId: SucceededTasksCount(+RunningTasksCount-FailedTasksCount)/TotalTasksCount [StageCost]
2017-12-03 16:55:27,468 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:30,528 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:33,585 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:37,557 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:40,617 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:43,683 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:46,764 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:49,822 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:52,900 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:55,945 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:55:58,999 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:02,077 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:05,134 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:08,196 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:11,238 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:14,280 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:17,345 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:20,380 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:23,405 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:26,464 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:29,534 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:32,598 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:35,627 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:38,661 Stage-0_0: 0/1
2017-12-03 16:56:41,718 Stage-0_0: 0/1
....
...
```

I have added the spark-assembly-xx*....jar in the `/usr/lib/hive/lib` path.
I have also added the following properties in `hive-site.xml`.

```
<property>
  <name>spark.master</name>
  <value>spark://192.168.190.128:7077</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.home</name>
  <value>/usr/lib/spark</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.eventLog.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/lib/hive/spark_log</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
  <value>512m</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.serializer</name>
  <value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.executor.cores</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>spark.driver.memory</name>
  <value>1024m</value>
</property>
```

I have also created the directory for property name `<name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>` as given in its value `<value>/usr/lib/hive/spark_log</value>`.
I even tried setting the `spark.master` as `spark://localhost.localdomain:7077`.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you just install CDH 5.6? That's quite old... Does Cloudera Manager say spark is healthy?